# Access a collection of arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to access elements in what looks like a comma separated list of arrays?

```
[
    ["service_state", "service_description", "service_icons", "svc_plugin_output", "svc_state_age", "svc_check_age", "perfometer"],
    ["OK", "Check_MK", "", "OK- Agent version 1.2.4p4, execution time 0.1 sec", "2017-05-01 21:11:33", "13 sec", "0.1s"]
]
```

The actual string contains more than two arrays and I wasn't sure how to access this using javascript to go through each element.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like an array of arrays

Comment: So you loop over the array and than you loop over the array in the index. Basic nested loops.

Comment: Simple multidimensional array. For example `console.log(array[0][0])` will print out "service_state".

Comment: Kinda the same way you would a normal array `arrayOfArrays[0][0]` FYI they're normally referred to as [multidimensional arrays or two-dimension arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Multi-dimensional_arrays)

Comment: Thanks,everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://jsfiddle.net/w2amcpbq/ or the below snippet:

```js
var multiArr = [
  [
    "service_state",
    "service_description",
    "service_icons",
    "svc_plugin_output",
    "svc_state_age",
    "svc_check_age",
    "perfometer"
  ],
  [
    "OK",
    "Check_MK",
    "",
    "OK - Agent version 1.2.4p4, execution time 0.1 sec",
    "2017-05-01 21:11:33",
    "13 sec",
    "0.1s"
  ]
];

var i = 0,
  arrLength = multiArr.length;
for (i; i < arrLength; i++) {
  var nestedArr = multiArr[i];
  console.log(nestedArr);
  for (var j = 0; j < nestedArr.length; j++) {
    console.log(nestedArr[j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access multidimensional array you just do

`array[0][0]` for the first element of the first sub array

On 3 levels it would be the same

```
array = [ [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ] ], 7 ];
```

`array[0][1][1]` will give 5

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you want to loop over all the elements, and originally you have an string.

```js
var text = '[["service_state","service_description","service_icons","svc_plugin_output","svc_state_age","svc_check_age","perfometer"],["OK","Check_MK","","OK - Agent version 1.2.4p4, execution time 0.1 sec","2017-05-01 21:11:33","13 sec","0.1s"]]';
var array = JSON.parse(text);

array.forEach(function(nested) {
  nested.forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
for each (arr in multiArr) {
    for each (v in arr) {
       print(v)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a multidimensional array.  Think of it as a set of rows and columns.  You access individual elements like this: array[row][column].

For example:

```
var arr = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]];
arr[0][0] //this results in 0
arr[0][1] //this results in 1
arr[1][0] //this results in 3
```

Following this logic you can loop through the array by using a nested for loop (loop inside a loop).

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // outer loop for rows
  for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) { // inner loop for columns
    console.log(arr[i][j])
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Aldo!